# Javascript Custom Button Issue

Tags: javascript, custom-button, jquery

Something Very strange issue , I observed today.

Create a detail page button on contact (didn tried for other object) and behaviour as Execute JavaScript

and paste the below code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/' & LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),':',''),'-',''),' ',''),10) & '000/jQuery')}
alert('Hi');
```

After I add the button in page layout, I have to click the button twice to get the alert. The first click went in vain and after second click I get the alert. I thought it is a browser issue but its the same in all browsers as well.

Now If i change this to

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

alert('Hi');
```

Then it responds on the first click itself. The third line which is removed is the static resource for Jquery library. I am not sure how this is a problem and why on adding this line , I have to click the button twice.

Any ideas to understand this behaviour will be greatful....

Comment: I am not sure that it can be a reason, but try to use API more up to date instead of 29. Current API version is 42

Comment: yes I put 42 as well but no luck...and also the problem is more on the third line... no issues with connection and apex js files

Comment: I even tried loading the static resource via URLFOR {!REQUIRESCRIPT("URLFOR($Resource.jQuery)")}

Comment: Maybe the script is loaded after the first button click? Looks weird though, why use the `SUBSTITUTE` method?

Comment: i tried using URL for as well and same results. Do you have any other way of loading the same whcih can prevent this double click